# Bokeh tap tool selects on vertical line

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a histogram plot with some very small bars.  I would like to make it easier to users to Tap on these bars.

[image]

Ideally I would like to mimic the behavior in [this HoverTool example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields) that uses `mode='vline'`.  Unfortunately it looks like that option is not available for the TapTool.  Is this correct?  Or is there some other way to obtain single-axis tapping.

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh `0.12.10` Bokeh's built in `TapTool` only uses point selection geometries. Adding support for line hit testing represents new feature development, so a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) would be appropriate. Alternatively, you could create a [custom extension](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) of your own.